# Firefox chrome:// document URLs

Tags: firefox

Mozilla has [documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Chrome_URLs) on Firefox's Chrome URLs, but the list is rather incomplete. I found another [article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:_Firefox_Chrome_URLs) on the same topic, but unfortunately, the information is terribly out-of-date (Firefox 1.0). The first article does give instructions for finding Chrome URLs, but before I spend time making my own list, I am wondering if a more complete list already exists.

Comment: Here is some more:
[Firefox chrome URLs](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:_Firefox_Chrome_URLs)

Comment: I have already linked to that page in my question. That page has not been updated since 2009 and is severely outdated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I could not find a better list, so after diggin through Firefox's various dialogs and windows, I present the following... Relevant as of **Firefox 10**.

- Main Window

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
  ```
- Page Setup

  ```
  chrome://global/content/printPageSetup.xul
  ```
- Customize Toolbar

  ```
  chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul
  ```
- Options

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/preferences/preferences.xul
  ```
- Connection Settings

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/preferences/connection.xul
  ```
- Update History

  ```
  chrome://mozapps/content/update/history.xul
  ```
- About Mozilla Firefox

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/aboutDialog.xul
  ```

---

### History & Bookmarks

- Library

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul
  ```
- Bookmarks Sidebar

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksPanel.xul
  ```
- History Sidebar

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/history/history-panel.xul
  ```
- Downloads

  ```
  chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/downloads.xul
  ```
- Clear All History

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/sanitize.xul
  ```
- Cookies

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/preferences/cookies.xul
  ```

### Content:

- Advanced JavaScript Settings

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/preferences/advanced-scripts.xul
  ```
- Fonts

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/preferences/fonts.xul
  ```
- Colors

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/preferences/colors.xul
  ```
- Languages

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/preferences/languages.xul
  ```

### Passwords:

- Exceptions - Saved Passwords

  ```
  chrome://passwordmgr/content/passwordManagerExceptions.xul
  ```
- Saved Passwords

  ```
  chrome://passwordmgr/content/passwordManager.xul
  ```
- Change Master Password

  ```
  chrome://mozapps/content/preferences/changemp.xul
  ```
- Remove Master Password

  ```
  chrome://mozapps/content/preferences/removemp.xul
  ```
- Reset Master Password

  ```
  chrome://pippki/content/resetpassword.xul
  ```

### Encryption:

- Certificate Manager

  ```
  chrome://pippki/content/certManager.xul
  ```
- Manage CRLS

  ```
  chrome://pippki/content/crlManager.xul
  ```
- Certificate Validation

  ```
  chrome://mozapps/content/preferences/ocsp.xul
  ```
- Device Manager

  ```
  chrome://pippki/content/device_manager.xul
  ```

### Developer:

- Error Console

  ```
  chrome://global/content/console.xul
  ```
- Scratchpad

  ```
  chrome://browser/content/scratchpad.xul
  ```

Comment: where does the "chrome" name comes from ?